# Is it possible to set the optimization level for RhinoScriptEngine in Java 6?

Tags: java, rhino

I am running into the issue where Rhino throws the ["Encountered code generation error while compiling script: generated bytecode for method exceeds 64K limit"](http://blog.gmane.org/gmane.comp.mozilla.devel.jseng.rhino/month=20080601/page=9) exception when running Rhino via the `javax.script.ScriptEngine` API. The accepted solution appears to be to invoke `setOptimizationLevel(-1)` on the `sun.org.mozilla.javascript.Context`.

Unfortunately, I cannot seem to access the `Context` that is created by the `ContextFactory`. I have tried adding a `ContextFactory.Listener` to `ContextFactory.getGlobal()` that would modify the `Context` after creation, but my listener never seems to get called. I also took a look at the [RhinoScriptEngine source from Java 6](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/com/sun/script/javascript/RhinoScriptEngine.java.html) to see whether there was a property that I could set that the `ContextFactory` would read from in order to determine the value of the optimization level.

As far as I can tell, in Java 7, `RhinoScriptEngine` sets the optimization level to `-1` by default *and* makes it possible to set the optimization level via the `rhino.opt.level` property. Compare the `makeContext()` method in the [Java 7 version](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/com/sun/script/javascript/RhinoScriptEngine.java.html) with the `makeContext()` method in the [Java 6 version](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/com/sun/script/javascript/RhinoScriptEngine.java.html) to see what I mean.

As far as I can tell, I believe that my best option is to run Rhino directly, as shown [in this example of using Rhino to run the CoffeeScript compiler](https://github.com/yeungda/jcoffeescript/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jcoffeescript/JCoffeeScriptCompiler.java). Though as you can see, the code is a lot messier, so I would prefer to use the `javax.script.ScriptEngine` API, if possible, while continuing to support Java 6. Are there any other options?

Comment: One other option is to copy all of the code from the com.sun.script.javascript package into a new package (or possibly the same one with renamed classes to access package-private members) and change the implementation of makeContext() to set the optimization level, but that seems like overkill.

Comment: I met same problem. 'Nashorn' in JDK8 is a more advanced JS engine, Nashorn can resolve the 64K problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**, according to the documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html#jsengine

Where it says:

> A few components have been excluded due to footprint and security reasons:
>
> 1. JavaScript-to-bytecode compilation (also called "optimizer"). This
>      feature depends on a class generation library. The removal of this
>      feature means that **JavaScript will always be interpreted**. The
>      removal of this feature does not affect script execution because the
>      optimizer is transparent.

The optimizer class has been excluded for bundling it with JDK6 therefore optimization level cannot be set for java 6.

Comment: But isn't that equivalent to an optimization level of -1, which is what the OP wanted? Surely code generation compilation errors should not be occurring under Java 6 if it's always interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

I'm running with 6 and it also appears to be set to -1 by default. Or rather, unless `sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.optimizer.Codegen` is on the classpath, it's set to -1.

Comment: Hmm, one problem may be that I am using the OpenJDK:

$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_22"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.10.2) (6b22-1.10.2-0ubuntu1~11.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)

The Sun JDK seems to have some differences around Rhino.

We had to do some pretty strange things to get things to work on both JDKs for my project, plovr:

http://code.google.com/p/plovr/source/detail?r=7e3cad7f1b9d